# Smaller row spacing for multirow

Tags: line-spacing, multirow

I have a table as in the figure and code below. The problem is that it really hard to see that the cells 22-34 belongs to the multirow R-23. I would like to reduce the row spacing for these to rows to bring them close to each other. How would I do that?
Preferably it is a global setting that reduces the row spacing for all multi-rows.

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{*4l}\toprule
    \textbf{R1}                    & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{R2-3}} & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
                                   & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
    \textbf{R4}                    & 42 & 43 & 44 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\\` has an optional argument, meaning the vertical space added. Hence you can rewrite your example as (the value is left to your taste):

```
\begin{tabular}{*4l}\toprule
    \textbf{R1}                    & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{R2-3}} & 22 & 23 & 24 \\[-3pt] % here is the change
                                   & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
    \textbf{R4}                    & 42 & 43 & 44 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but you have to add this for every multirow you use, and this will cause some headaches if I decide to change the distance in the document. Anyway to make this change 'permanent' and reusable?

Comment: @T'n'E For example `\def\NH{\\[-3pt]}` and use this definition in place of the shown change. `\NH` is for `No Headaches`. :-)

Comment: Great! Now I use `\setlength\extrarowheight{7pt}` and `\def\NH{\\[-\extrarowheight]}` to cancel out the extra space for multirows. Not optimal, but not too much hassle.

Answer (score 4):

You also  can use the `\addlinespace` command from booktabs. The value of `\defaultaddspace` can be adjusted in preamble. I also slightly simplified the code for the first column:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ > {\bfseries}l*3l}
  \toprule
  R1 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
  \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{*}{R2-3} & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
                        & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
  \addlinespace
  R4 & 42 & 43 & 44 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the simplified syntax. Keep forgetting that trick. Is there any benefit using `\addlinespace` compared to `\\[-3pt]`? If I understand it correctly, this would have to be added to all rows _not_ multirow, which in my case is the majority of rows. There is no `\removelinespace`?

Comment: No real benefit, except a form of coherence (using the tools of booktabs) and, more seriously, be sure you the *same* amount when necessary throughout you document. You still may change its value locally, using the optionalargument to \addlinespace. For the second part of your comment, it would be used as a separator only between a \multirow and its neighbours.

Comment: Ah, yes, now I see, but that also means that if I add another row, `R5`, the distance between `R4` and `R5` would be equal to that of the multirow. One can then argue which is more readable…

Comment: Yes, it will have the ‘general’ distance. Personnally, I prefer that solution but it's a matter of taste. Also, don't forget, with`\setdefaultaddspace`,  you can modulate this spacing.